# Select sum while selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select some values, and I have used the query below:

```
SELECT 
    l.*,SUM(lp.amount) AS landPayMonth,p.pName,u.uName,SUM(ci.amount) AS totAmnt,
    t.unitId
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT landlord_payment.id,landlord_payment.amount,landlord_payment.landlordId FROM landlord_payment) lp,
    (SELECT DISTINCT cashIn.id,cashIn.tenantId,cashIn.registeredTime,cashIn.amount FROM cashIn) ci,landlords l,properties p,units u,tenants t
WHERE
    ci.tenantId = t.id
        AND l.id = lp.landlordId
        AND t.unitId = u.id
        AND u.propertyId = p.id
        AND p.landlordId = l.id
        AND STR_TO_DATE(ci.registeredTime, '%Y-%m') = STR_TO_DATE(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY l.id;
```

SOme part of the result I get after running the query above is:

```
id  fName  lName     landPayMonth pName           uName   totAmnt   unitId  
1   Kigen  Chemweno  100000       Smart Apartments Hse 21 32200     1
```

landPayMonth and totAmnt produces wrong results. Everything else is ok.
Some sections of some of the tables are as follows:
cashIn

```
    tenantId    amount  registeredTime  
        2        8000   2017-06-02 17:48:34
        1        20100  2017-05-10 10:04:46
        1        100    2017-06-08 10:31:02
        2        6000   2017-06-05 14:34:13
        2        2000   2017-06-07 14:15:30
```

landlords

```
id  fName   lName
1   Kigen   Chemweno
3   Samwel  Ekiru
```

Properties

```
id  pName             landlordId
1   Smart Apartments    1
2   Iten Star           3
```

Tenants

```
id  fName       lName    unitId
1   Florence    Cheptum     1
2   Rose        Boit        2
```

Units

```
id  uName   propertyId
1   Hse 21  1
2   Hse 20  1
```

landlord_payment

```
id  landlordId  amount
1   1           20000
3   1           5000
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: would you please write in words what do you want to find by this query ?

Comment: I want to get the sum of amount from both cashIn and landlord_payment tables